I have been getting Could not find the correct Provider<RegisterProvider> above this Selector <RegisterProvider, TextEditingController> Widget
I'm very new to flutter and provider and I ran into this error and I've searched a lot of ways to fix it including ChatGPT and StackOverflow but I couldn't find a way. Below is my code base
class RegisterScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const RegisterScreen({super.key});

  @override
  RegisterScreenState createState() => RegisterScreenState();

  static Widget builder(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => RegisterProvider(),
      child: const RegisterScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class RegisterScreenState extends State<RegisterScreen> {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        body: Center(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
              bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom,
            ),
            child: SizedBox(
              height: SizeUtils.height,
              child: Form(
                key: _formKey,
                child: Container(
                  width: double.maxFinite,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(26.h),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      SizedBox(height: 20.v),
                      _buildRegistrationForm(context),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildEmailInput(BuildContext context) {
    return Selector<RegisterProvider, TextEditingController>(
      selector: (context, provider) => provider.emailInputController,
      builder: (context, emailInputController, child) {
        return CustomTextFormField(
          controller: emailInputController,
          hintText: 'Email address',
          textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
          textInputType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
          validator: (value) {
            if (value == null || (!isValidEmail(value, isRequired: true))) {
              return 'Please enter a valid email address';
            }
            return null;
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildRegistrationForm(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 6.h),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            CustomImageView(
              imagePath: ImageConstant.imgArrowLeft,
              height: 24.adaptSize,
              width: 24.adaptSize,
              onTap: () {
                onTapBackImgArrow(context);
              },
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 50.v),
            Text(
              'Register',
              style: theme.textTheme.headlineSmall,
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 30.v),
            _buildEmailInput(context),
            const Spacer(),
            CustomElevatedButton(
              text: 'Continue',
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                left: 12.h,
                right: 6.h,
              ),
              alignment: Alignment.center,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void onTapBackImgArrow(BuildContext context) {
    NavigatorService.goBack();
  }


I've tried to use Provider.of but I still get errors and i've searched here in StackOverflow but there seems to be no solution related to my problem. Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated as I am still learning and this will greatly help me to learn and improve as I build.

You should provide RegisterProvider at the top of that widget using Provider widget.
Provider(
  create: (_) => RegisterProvider(),
  child: RegisterScreen()
)

